# Turn off manifest.js generation in Nuxt full static generation

Tags: nuxt.js

How do I turn off the generation of `manifest.js` which contains the routes for full static generation. I have a Nuxt app with ~150k routes and this `manifest.js` file takes around ~12 MB in size. This feature was added in this commit (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/commit/691f21c6832323902d899b56566dd97d63683528#diff-ba07960f44050961fcce0824ffa64cdbf93ef44a64329d5eeea765b616a5e9e7) and may affect versions 2.14.8 and up

code reference:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/9681a8937d0c973bc685b757faa686023a4536fc/packages/generator/src/generator.js#L61
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/9681a8937d0c973bc685b757faa686023a4536fc/packages/generator/src/generator.js#L32

Answer (score 3):

In `nuxt.config.js`, set `generate.manifest` to `false`